# compile matlab linux binary

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have a license for the matlab compiler and can compile exe files fine. Is there any way to compile my project into a Linux binary from my windows machine?

Answer (score 2):

No, the compile and deploy architecture must be the same.